# My program compiled, but when running i got this error?

Tags: java

Okay, it compiled, but when i tried to run the program i got this error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: (No such file or directory) at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106) at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:636) at EncryptionDecryption.getString(EncryptionDecryption.java:32) at EncryptionDecryption.main(EncryptionDecryption.java:14)`

I AM SO CONFUSED 
 I think this is where its coming from

```
static String getString()  throws FileNotFoundException {
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(" "));
String codeString = input.next();
return codeString;
}

static void putString (String finalString) throws FileNotFoundException {
PrintWriter work = new PrintWriter("EncryptedDocument.txt");
work.print(finalString + " ");
work.close();
}
```

Comment: Please provide a piece of code that throws that exception, but it seems that file path you provided is wrong.

Comment: you tried to read a non-existent file... The argument pf scanner is most probably the culprit.

Comment: No one will be able to help you based on what you've provided since we can't guess what's your code about. Please describe your problem properly, post the code that throws the exception.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is broken:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(" "));
```

That's trying to open a file called " ". I suspect you don't have such a file - it would be a pretty unusual filename.

Where did you *want* to read your input from? Actually a file, or from the console?

EDIT: As per comments, if you want to read from the console, use

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: from a user input, so the console. How do i go about doing that?

Comment: Use `new Scanner(System.in)` - but I'm confused as to why you *tried* the code you've got. It's clearly dealing with a file - you're calling the `File` constructor. Why did you do that if you didn't want a file?

Comment: Well i think i did want a file but assume that using a console input would be easier? how would i use an actual file instead?

Comment: @GregoryBonilla: You would give the name of an actual file which exists... unlike a file with a filename of a single space.

Comment: @JonSkeet Glad to see you keeping your sense of humour. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading/writing off any file ?
The error log hints at that(no such file). 
Please post some code to zero down on what may be going on.